# Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions<User>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I am trying to build a backend with express.js. I now have the following problem:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { getManager } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "../entity/user.entity";


export const GetUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const repository = getManager().getRepository(User);

  const { password, ...user } = await repository.findOne(req.params.id);

  res.send(user);
};
```

The following error always occurs:

(parameter) req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>
Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions'.ts(2559)
[image]
router.ts

```
router.get("/api/users/:id", AuthMiddleware, GetUser);
```

user.entity.ts

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { Role } from "./role.entity";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  first_name: string;
  @Column()
  last_name: string;
  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "role_id" })
  role: Role;
}
```

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The typeorm's `findOne` function is equivalent to `Select * ... limit 1`. This means that the `findOne` actually expects an object containing conditions to match and return the first element for which the condition is satisfied.

In your case, the code should be:

```js
repository.findOne({where: {id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10)}})
```

or

```js
repository.findOneBy({id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10)})
```

This will find the user whose `id` field will match match the `req.params.id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried both solutions but it doesnt work. (property) id?: number | FindOperator<number>
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | FindOperator<number>'.ts(2322)

Comment: @bobby17jones,  This is because `req.params.id` is a string where as in your code the `id` is Int. Just use #parseInt function and this will work.

Comment: @bobby17jones updated the answer to fix your issue.

Answer (score 9):

Anyone migrating from **NestJs v7** to **v9** will run into this issue because they use **different TypeORM versions**.

Turns out this was a breaking change on **TypeORM** side.

Going from **v0.2.x** to **v0.3.x** has this breaking change they dropped the `findOne(id)` method in favor of `findOneBy({where : {id: id}})`
Check Here: https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1 
[image: Breaking Changes in TypeORM]

I have TypeORM v0.3.12:
[image: TypeORM version]

Here I get the same error
[image: Error]

Now the error is resolved:
[image]

This video rang the bell for me:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEFEze_SQKU

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button. And for documentation, mark it as a blockquote.

Answer (score 2):

according to manual, use the { criteria: search }
so

`findOneBy({id: req.params.id});`